# AWS Lambda basic print function

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, architecture, analysis, amazon-quicksight

Why am I unable to make an AWS Lambda python print function in console? It shows successfully executed but in results I never see my desired print words.

I used this code and it showed following execution result-

````
target = "blue"
prediction = "red"
print(file_name,target,prediction, (lambda: '+' if target==prediction else '-')) ```





**Execution result-**
```Response:
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "body": "\"Hello from Lambda!\""
}

Request ID:
"xxxxxxx"

Function logs:
START RequestId: xxxxxx Version: $LATEST
END RequestId: xxxxxx
REPORT RequestId: xxxx  Duration: 1.14 ms   Billed Duration: 100 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 52 MB
````

Comment: To get a helpful answer you need to post a lot more details. How are you trying to print, where are you looking for the output, etc

Comment: Where are you looking for the "results"?

Comment: Ani can You edit Your question and paste lambda body?

Answer (score 5):

If your AWS Lambda function uses Python, then any `print()` statement will be sent to the logs.

The logs are displayed when a function is manually run in the console. Also, l**ogs are sent the Amazon CloudWatch Logs** for later reference.

Ensure that your Lambda function has been assigned the `AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole`, which includes permission to write the CloudWatch Logs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I checked Amazon CloudWatch Logs and it shows start, end and report Request Ids only. I tried to create basic lambda function using python in console but it always shows successfully executed and some Ids and never print the code result.

Comment: Did you include some `print()` statements in the "basic lambda function"? Did those print messages appear in CloudWatch Logs?

Comment: Yes I included print statements but nothing showed up in cloud watch logs except some Id.

Comment: That suggests that the IAM Role assigned to the function does not have permission to write to CloudWatch Logs. Have you assigned the `AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole` policy to the IAM Role?

Comment: I had the same problem. I was clicking the test button without clicking deploy, thinking that it would automatically update the code. It didn't. Try clicking deploy and after test. You should see the print statements.

Comment: Can confirm that I had this issue also and was fixed by deploying the function.